# How can I set a dynamic env variable for dev vs prod @ionic/app-scripts?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am a complete noobie on the ionic/webpack build process, but for this task I am referring specifically to this: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts#environments. I don't quite fully understand what is meant by "If the variable exists in the process environment it will be replaced with that value."

The scripts in my package.json are as follows:

```
"scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build --dev",
    "build:after": "",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
}
```

From what I understand, I should be able to set up an env variable, say process.env.BASE_URL for example, anywhere in my code that could be a different value depending on the build.

My question is how do I structure my script to set that variable in my process environment? Is it just a matter of setting the "build" script as "BASE_URL=myurl ionic-app-scripts build --dev"? And if it really is that easy, how would I then access the script for the --prod flag to set the variable for that one as well? 
Thank you in advance. I really love this community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost correct. Usually, the way that I do things is to define an item in my scripts config like `"ionic:build:prod" : "BASE_URL=myurl ionic-app-scripts build --prod`. That way you can run that whole thing with one easy command(`npm run ionic:build:prod`)